# Programmatically get last boot/shutdown time

Tags: python, windows, event-log

I'd like to get the exact time when windows was shut down and booted.
In c++ I'd simply use `GetTickCount64` which retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started (thus obtaining the time by difference), but I don't know if there is an equivalent function for python and, if possible, I'd like to avoid to write a c++ module.

For last shutdown time I have no idea...maybe there is some log somewhere in windows? I tried to read the event log using `win32evtlog` library, but it gives me just an event and is about the dns..

**edit:
Ok, maybe I got a step further: I used win32evtlog, in particular calling ReadEvent log more times it gives me all logs till it returns null. 
Now, I need a way to understand what ids are about boot/shutdown..**

Comment: You can access Win32 API calls with the [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) library. Regarding the last shutdown, it seems related to event with id 6006([source](http://www.guidingtech.com/432/last-shutdown-time-windows/)).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the pywin32 library, and there you'll find the GetTickCount() function.

http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__GetTickCount_meth.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about knowing the last shutdown?

Comment: Well, using the GetTickCount() function is easy... just substract the result of the function call from the current time.

Comment: Not really, that would give you the last start-up time; not the last shut-down time

Comment: Yep, that's true, sorry. You can use the same library in order to process the event logs, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Windows specific question, we can leverage from both WMI and, even PowerShell. To solve your problem in PowerShell, it's just:

```
powershell -command "(gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime"
# Outputs: Tuesday, 9 October 2018 4:05:58 PM
```

To do this in Python, we can make use of `subprocess`:

```
from subprocess import call
call( ["powershell", "-command", "(gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime"] )
# Outputs: Tuesday, 9 October 2018 4:05:58 PM
```