# Modifying value of a variable until computer shuts down?

Tags: python, raspbian, uptime

I'm writing a program in python which has three modules: 
1. settings.py
2. init.py
3. main.py

settings.py just has one Boolean variable, the goal is to use it as a global variable(let's call it var, initialised as `False` ) across modules

init.py imports the var, and sets it to `True` after performing some actions in a function

main.py has to check whether `var == True`. If yes, proceed with the program else ask user to give some command line instructions (say, prg start) which will then call a function in init.py, which in turn will also set `var==True`

The problem is that since I have made a program that takes arguments from CLI, the `var` is always set to False. So the only command that CLI accepts is `prg start` else it prints the error message that I have written.

I need some method to let `var` stay `True` for rest of the session, and session actually translates to until computer is switched off.

code for main.py

```
first = sys.argv[0]
arguments = sys.argv[1:]

second = arguments[0]


if settings.var == False and second != "start":
    print "Error, type \'prg start\' to start"
    sys.exit(0)

if second == "start":
    init.start()
```

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

> pi@raspberrypi: ~$ prg start
>
> pi@raspberrypi: ~$ prg set color 4
>
> Success

what is happening right now:

> pi@raspberrypi: ~$ prg start
>
> pi@raspberrypi: ~$ prg set color 4
>
> Error, type 'prg start' to start

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AndrewNaguib if it means posting init.py and settings.py then sure!

Comment: Post an example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AndrewNaguib can you please check now. I'm sorry, I'm not a native english speaker and it's a little hard to explain

Comment: @PatrickArtner Linux, but Raspbian (on raspberry pi) to be precise. Almost as same as Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file to store the variable permanently!

Comment: Do you mean that instead of using global variable I should use a file and read and write that? In that case, how can the variable become `False` automatically if I shutdown?

Comment: Exactly as mentioned by @patrick-artner! Use the filename as the last boot time. That way, you have a new file for each boot.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of persistent storage that goes away on shutdown. It must also be persistent although your program is not currently running.

Solutions that come to mind:

**File:**

Write the last boot time into a file, also add last `'prg start`  time - figure out if latter came after former:

- Linux: `last reboot` + *datetime* of your last `'prg start'`  call - you can figure out if reboot came before/after
- Windows: `systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"` (Or whatever it is called in your language), same principle

The file does not vanish, but your "last reboot time" will reset on reboot. You could simply get away with collecting`'prg start'` timestamps in your file and check "live" against the current value of "last reboot" if started with other parameters.

**Server/Client:**

Spawn an independent "server" process on first `'prg start'` - check if that process runs using

- pipe-communication "You there?" - silence .vs. "You there?" - "YEP" (f.e. [Python multiprocessing - pipe communication between processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110733/python-multiprocessing-pipe-communication-between-processes))
- or check if an instance of your "server" is already running (f.e. [Make sure only a single instance of a program is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/make-sure-only-a-single-instance-of-a-program-is-running))

The "server" process will vanish on reboot (or when manually killed - but so does the file if you delete it...)

Related:

- [Programmatically get last boot/shutdown time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063346/programmatically-get-last-boot-shutdown-time)
- [Fastest way to get system uptime in Python in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471475/fastest-way-to-get-system-uptime-in-python-in-linux)

Comment: Thanks @patrickartner. For this I'll need a python script that can automatically write `who` command and parse the `date and time` from it. Can you guide me in an appropriate direction? Also, how can I get `date-time` for `prg start`?

Comment: @Total No I can not guide you. Lookup the [module datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)  and its `.now()` method to get the current time. You can search if the systeminfo command is already python wrapped - if not, call it from your script and pipe the result into a file (f.e.) and read that in and get the stuff you need from it. Divide and conquer the tasks you need to accomplish - if you get stuck on one of them, ask a new question.